# Custom Sorting in Laravel depending on column value

Tags: mysql, sql, database, laravel, eloquent

I want to sort a table entries. Here is the Eloquent Model.

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

/**
 * App\Story
 ...
 * @property string $due_date
 * @property string $status late|scheduled|completed
 ...
 */
class Story extends Model {
    ...
}
```

The order in which i want to return the Stories are:

- **"late"** is ASC (Older first)
- **"scheduled"** in DSC ( New first)
- **"completed"** in DSC ( New first)

So Let's assume there are 15 entries in db for each status type of story. and the Pagination limit is set to be 20.

so here is the response of each page

- First Page: 15 Late Stories in ASC order + first 5 Scheduled Stories in DSC order
- Second Page: Remaining 10 Scheduled Stories + first 10 Completed Stories in DSC order
- Third Page: remaining 5 Completed Stories

Please do let me know if the information provided above is not sufficient. Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir I have a working solution. But there are two issues with it: 1. Highly unoptimised and won't work for more complex sorting ( Which our project will be needing sooner or later)

Comment: So the working Solution is: add a number column **factor** that stores -3 for late and 2 for scheduled and 1 for completed. Then while maintaining rows, update the values whenever values of type is updated.. and the query will be sort timestamp(due_date) * factor DSC

Answer (score 1):

Not ideal, but works without a `factor` column:

```php
Story::orderByRaw('FIELD(status, "late", "scheduled", "completed")')
    ->orderByRaw('(CASE WHEN status = "late" THEN 1 ELSE -1 END) * due_date')
    ->paginate(10);
```

When multiplied by an integer, `due_date` automatically gets converted to a string (`20180609`). So it should be faster than `timestamp(due_date)`.

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for. Will give it a try. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, you may want to use a custom order sql for a specific column. To achieve this, you can use `orderColumn` api.

In this example, we will order the column name with nulls as last result.

```
use DataTables;

Route::get('user-data', function() {
$model = App\User::query();

return DataTables::eloquent($model)
            ->orderColumn('name', '-name $1')
            ->toJson();
});
```

Comment: Hi, Your answer mentions about a single column sorting. I want to sort considering two columns that too order of second column depends on the value of first column. Please do let me know if you have a solution for that. Thanks